# Cannot Connect to DISPLAY from docker container

Tags: docker, display

I am following a basic tutorial in which we run `abiword` (some gui) from a docker container. For some reason, the container cannot find my display.
I am running on Ubuntu 20.04, on a x86_64 machine.
My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update && apt install -y abiword
CMD abiword
```

My build command:
`docker build -t abiword .`

Before my run command, I add docker to my authorized xhosts:

```
mylinux@mylinux:$ xhost +local:docker
non-network local connections being added to access control list
mylinux@mylinux:$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
LOCAL:
SI:localuser:lu20
```

I also tried `xhost +` to disable access control altogether, but no luck.

Run commands I've tried:

`docker run -e DISPLAY=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix abiword`

`docker run -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix abiword`

`docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix abiword`

The volume I'm mounting does exist:

```
mylinux@mylinux:$ ls /tmp/.X11-unix/
X0  X1
```

In all cases, I get the same output:

```
** (abiword:7): WARNING **: 13:46:51.920: clutter failed 0, get a life.
No DISPLAY: this may not be what you want.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $DISPLAY` on the host?

Comment: @Garuno The output is `:1`

Comment: Your second two `docker run ...` commands work for me. Note that when using the unix socket in `/tmp/.X11-unit` (which is what you're doing) you don't need to muck around with `xhost`. Those commands worked on my system without any prior setup.

Comment: @larsks I removed local:docker from xhost and repeated everything and still the same result. Good to know that it worked on your system though.